# SQL Parent Child Tree Sort BY DEPTH and Display Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query that creates a hierarchy of Categories. It works great. Now I'm trying to control the Display order based on the Depth. For example I have a Category Called 'Cat'. It has two sub categories called 'Sub Cat 1' and 'Sub Cat 2'. Is it possible to sort the sub categories by Display Order and Depth? So the order will be ‘Sub Cat 2’ then ‘Sub Cat 1’, based on the display order. 
I want to be able to control the order of the categories Based on its location in Depth and Display Order.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @CategoryID INT; 
DECLARE @ExcludeInactive BIT; 

SET @CategoryID = 2; 
SET @ExcludeInactive = 0;

Declare @Categories Table
(
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(500),
    ParentID INT,
    Depth INT, 
    Active BIT,
    DisplayOrder INT
);

INSERT INTO @Categories
SELECT 2, 'Main', 0, 0, 1, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Cat', 2, 0, 1, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 'Sub Cat 1', 6, 1, 1, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 'Sub Cat 2', 6, 1, 1,    1
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Cat 2', 2,0, 1, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 'Sub Cat 1', 5, 1, 1, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 'Sub Cat 2', 5, 1, 1, 1;

WITH Tree (ID, Name, ParentID, Depth, Sort, Active, DisplayOrder) AS 
( 
    SELECT ID, Name, ParentID, 0 AS Depth, CONVERT(varchar(255), Name) AS Sort, Active,     DisplayOrder         
    FROM @Categories 
    WHERE ParentID = @CategoryID 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CT.ID, CT.Name, CT.ParentID, Parent.Depth + 1 AS Depth, 
    CONVERT(varchar(255), Parent.Sort + ' > ' + CT.Name) AS Sort, CT.Active, CT.DisplayOrder 
    FROM @Categories CT 
    INNER JOIN Tree as Parent ON Parent.ID = CT.ParentID WHERE (@ExcludeInactive = 0  OR (CT.Active = 1 ))   
) 


SELECT ID, Name, ParentID, Depth, Sort, Active, DisplayOrder FROM Tree ORDER BY SORT
```

**Current Output:**

```
ID  Name       ParentID   Depth  Sort             Active    DisplayOrder
6   Cat        2          0      Cat                  1         2
13  Sub Cat 1  6          1      Cat > Sub Cat 1      1         2
14  Sub Cat 2  6          1      Cat > Sub Cat 2      1         1
5   Cat 2      2          0      Cat 2                1         1
15  Sub Cat 1  5          1      Cat 2 > Sub Cat 1    1         2
16  Sub Cat 2  5          1      Cat 2 > Sub Cat 2    1         1
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ID  Name       ParentID   Depth  Sort             Active    DisplayOrder
5   Cat 2      2          0      Cat 2                1         1
16  Sub Cat 2  5          1      Cat 2 > Sub Cat 2    1         1
15  Sub Cat 1  5          1      Cat 2 > Sub Cat 1    1         2
6   Cat        2          0      Cat                  1         2
14  Sub Cat 2  6          1      Cat > Sub Cat 2      1         1
13  Sub Cat 1  6          1      Cat > Sub Cat 1      1         2
```

Comment: Question: Why is `DECLARE @CategoryID INT;` twice?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's been removed.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but you could do something like:

```
DECLARE @CategoryID INT; 
DECLARE @ExcludeInactive BIT; 

SET @CategoryID = 2; 
SET @ExcludeInactive = 0;

Declare @Categories Table
(
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(500),
    ParentID INT,
    Depth INT, 
    Active BIT,
    DisplayOrder INT
);

INSERT INTO @Categories
SELECT 2, 'Main', 0, 0, 1, 0
UNION
SELECT 6, 'Cat', 2, 0, 1, 0
UNION
SELECT 13, 'Sub Cat 1', 6, 1, 1, 2
UNION
SELECT 14, 'Sub Cat 2', 6, 1, 1,    1
UNION
SELECT 5, 'Cat 2', 2,0, 1, 0
UNION
SELECT 15, 'Sub Cat 1', 5, 1, 1, 2
UNION
SELECT 16, 'Sub Cat 2', 5, 1, 1, 1;

WITH Tree (ID, Name, ParentID, Depth, Sort, Active, DisplayOrder) AS 
( 
    SELECT ID, Name, ParentID, 0 AS Depth, CONVERT(varchar(255), Name) AS Sort, Active,     DisplayOrder         
    FROM @Categories 
    WHERE ParentID = @CategoryID 
    UNION  
    SELECT CT.ID, CT.Name, CT.ParentID, Parent.Depth + 1 AS Depth, 
    CONVERT(varchar(255), Parent.Sort + ' > ' + CT.Name) AS Sort, CT.Active, CT.DisplayOrder 
    FROM @Categories CT 
    INNER JOIN Tree as Parent ON Parent.ID = CT.ParentID WHERE (@ExcludeInactive = 0  OR (CT.Active = 1 ))   
) 

SELECT ID, Name, ParentID, Depth, Sort, Active, DisplayOrder 
FROM Tree 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(Sort,1,CHARINDEX(' >',Sort+' >')) DESC, DisplayOrder
```

Note, that all those `UNIONS` should be `ALL` but I am unable to post them due to a firewall quirk.

Comment: Either way this order by doesn't keep the sort field in the correct order.

Comment: Updated question helps, it's Cat 2 that throws things off.

Comment: That worked for the sub categories, but I doesn't work for the categories. I have updated Current/Desired outputs.

Comment: I don't understand the logic, you want subcategories above the main category sorted by display order, and you want main categories sorted by what?

Comment: I updated Desired Output, I hope that makes sense. I want the order of the Categories based on the Depth.

Comment: Updated answer again, is it arbitrary that Cat 2 is first and Cat is 2nd?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to control the order of the categories as well as their sub categories.